# How to create a React component without adding component to the JSX tree

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

I am building a simple custom table component using https://github.com/GeekyAnts/react-native-easy-grid. Now I have 4 custom components, Table, TRow, ThColumn, TdColumn. As you can guess this hierarchy works just as in Html and these components just adds some custom styles like making header text grey and not needed to write Text component every time etc. now when I build a table with my new and shiny components, it doesn't work.

This is what each of these components looks like.
Table

```
({children, ...props}) => <Grid {...props}><Text>{children}</Text></Grid>
```

TRow

```
({children, ...props}) => <Row {...props}><Text>{children}</Text></Row>
```

TdColumn/ThColumn

```
({children, ...props}) => <Col {...props}><Text>{children}</Text></Col>
```

As you can see these components are not doing very much. TRow and ThColumn have some custom styles like margin and colour but nothing related to flexbox.

This works

```
    <Grid>
      <Row>
        <Col><Text>Some Heading</Text></Col>
      </Row>
      <Row>
        <Col><Text>Some Text</Text></Col>
      </Row>
    </Grid>
```

This doesn't work (I am getting all the text in the same line)

```
    <Table>
      <TRow>
        <ThColumn>Some Heading</ThColumn>
      </TRow>
      <Trow>
        <TdColumn>Some Text</TdColumn>
      </Trow>
    </Table>
```

Now I think, because there is trow on top of row and thcolumn/tdcolumn on top of actual col this is breaking.

I would like answers for>

1. Am I right?
2. If I am right how can i create components which would return actual row and col instead of thcolumn and trow.

Comment: If you could provide the error you're receiving would be nice. The same for the code of every component. It's very hard to guess without knowing how the components have been coded.

Comment: @Nahue, I have updated my question, please check. I don't get any error. As I mentioned I don't get desired output. Row is supposed to take a new line. But in my case, all the text in both header row and body row comes in the same line.

Comment: Well, seeing that definitions, I can say that you're missing the Text component in the Col definition. I'm gonna write an answer.

Comment: I have excluded them to show you the idea of what the components are like. I have added them to the question, just to avoid any confusion.

Comment: You have a typo as well. In the second "Trow" should say "TRow". Be aware of that.

Comment: In order to be able to help you better, I recommend showing the full code in something like Codesandbox (see my answer)

Comment: @Nahue, That wasn't the problem. Clearly, I don't get any errors. My problem is related to this issue on Github https://github.com/GeekyAnts/react-native-easy-grid/issues/86

Comment: Nice, add it as an answer to yourself to everyone will know!

Answer (score 0):

Seeing your components definitions, I guess you're missing the Text component in the Col definition. Remember that **you cannot render text without using Text** in React Native.

So I'd define `Col` like this

```js
({children, ...props}) => <Col {...props}><Text>{children}</Text></Col>
```

Also you have a typo in the second "Trow". It should say "TRow".

Finally, it'd be desirable if you could provide the full components definitions in something like [Codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/q4qymyp2l6)

Hope it helps